# Are there any Jquery/Ajax like libraries in php?

Tags: php, ajax

Im a little confused about this. I've only used php and html till now and wish to make my site web2.0-ish like most ajax based sites are. Are there any libraries i can use based on php? I know php is server side.. is there a client side ajax library or something?

Comment: No its not.. Look im just confused.. I get it Jquery = Client Side Javascript code. Php= server side script. I just want to know if there any libraries with php-ish syntax for the client side

Comment: I think this person's used to ASP.NET.  D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the most documented tool out there, but one of the easier ways for a PHP person to put AJAX into your application is to look toward XAJAX (http://www.xajaxproject.com.  In a nutshell, you install XAJAX, pass calls through it to PHP functions, and it does the transaction asynchronously like AJAX, without having to write a ton of Javascript.  Be aware that you're not going to get completely away from Javascript, and there are many other solutions out there (such as Jquery, which is a great choice for many Javascript needs)  My only real complaint is that much of the XAJAX community is based in Europe, so the forums (in English) can get a bit garbled in translation.

My company uses a combination of the two partially because XAJAX feels more "comfortable" to php-only developers.  When we need something that's more robust, I nearly always go the Jquery route.

Answer (score 2):

Server Side: PHP

Client Side: HTML for markup (static content once it's served up by your PHP script) and JavaScript for scripting (making things happen dynamically in the user's browser)

Things like [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) are libraries (usually called frameworks in the Javascript world) built in JavaScript. There are a number of frameworks out there. [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a big one, [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/) is another popular one. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks to get a basic feel for the major players.

My suggestion: Spend a few hours writing a basic JavaScript tool following something like http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp When you have an understanding of what Javascript is capable of, start playing with one a framework.

Comment: Well thanks for that.. Makes things clearer.. So Jquery is my best bet? I CUD directly work with the XMLHttpRequest object right?

Comment: @Ram,

Both JQuery and Dojo allow you to easily work with XMLHttpRequest.

JQuery or Dojo? They're both good and are both used by a lot of developers. I've used both and like both. Seems that the StackOverflow community might be a bit partial to JQuery, but tons of high profile sites use Dojo. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs for a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

"is there a client side ajax library or something"

-That's what jQuery is.  Look at the .get() and .post() functions in jQuery.  They'll come in handy.

On the server side, in PHP, you treat it like a normal page load.